# Can not SUM selected cells With SUMIF

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to be able to Check for criteria "*owners*" In column A and SUM cell from the same row column E with the cell above and repeat through the spread sheet where owner is found.

I have tried to use Function `=SUMIF(A3,"*owner*",E2:E3)` This returns the Value above the cell in the row with owner but does not SUM them.

I have also tried this VBA CODE and it does the same thing.

```
Sub vba_sumif()

Dim gRange As Range
Dim sRange As Range

Set gRange = Range("A3")
Set sRange = Range("E2:E3")

Range("G2") = _
WorksheetFunction.SumIf(gRange,"*Owner*", sRange)

End Sub
```

[image]

Ideally it would return the summed cells in the above cell. using VBA

Thanks again,
Aaron

Comment: Could you share the exact results in columns G and H for the data in the screenshot? I mean, is it `118.98`?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, I would suggest just using the formula unless you have a reason not to:

**Formula::** Your first error with the formula is both ranges need to be the same size.

[image]
[image]

**VBA::** Same thing here with range sizes, then you also need to remember to make sure Excel knows what sheet you're referring to. I like to do this with a `With My_Worksheet_Name`statement, then include a `.` before any range from that sheet. Just make sure to change the sheet name to your sheet name

```
Option Explicit
Sub vba_sumif()
    
    Dim TableSheet As Worksheet
    Dim gRange As Range
    Dim sRange As Range
    
    Set TableSheet = Worksheets("TableSheet")
    With TableSheet
        
        Set gRange = .Range("A2:A13")
        Set sRange = .Range("E2:E13")
        
        .Range("G2").Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.SumIf(gRange, "*Owner*", sRange)
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did have it the way you recommended and got the same results where every owner stock was summed together. What I need to do is Sum the owners stock with the cell above only, then go to the next occurrence and repeat. I do not want to sum all owner together. Thank you